# No MySQL result until WHERE specified

Tags: php, mysql, count

I've been using simple MySQL commands for years, and wanted to get into more complicated ones. I've taken the task to rewrite some of my old code, but I can't see what's happening here.

I'm trying to merge two tables into one reults, with the second table only providing a "count".

```
TABLE customers:
customerID, name, boxID
TABLE codes:
boxID, code, retrieved
```

What I want is exactly what I get from a SELECT * FROM customer, but I want an extra column which has the count() for all codes in the codes table where the boxID is the same.

This is my current query;

```
SELECT customers.*, count(codes.code) as codesused 
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN codes 
ON customers.boxID = codes.boxID
WHERE codes.retrieved = 1
```

Which results in NULL until I add a "WHERE customers.customerID = 'x'". Would anyone be able to explain why I can't get what I want from the above code?

Comment: You can create a sample scenario at http://sqlfiddle.com/ which you can link here for us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When u combine aggregate function with other fields, You have to use group by clause. You can make your query like this;

```
SELECT customerID, name, boxID, count(codes.code) as codesused 
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN codes ON customers.boxID = codes.boxID 
GROUP BY customerID, name, boxID, codesused
HAVING codes.retrieved = 1
```

And you can't use where clause with group by, so you have to use HAVING

Comment: AH, forgot about the `GROUP BY`, you are correct there. The `codes_retrieved=1` would more probably go in the join `ON` condition though, but I'll leave that to clarify for the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll test it's working and verify your answer. Logically, seems intact. Moved on to another part of the code which isn't long from finished.

Comment: Everything works apart from the HAVING clause. Basically, the only codes that should count in the count() are the ones that have retrieved = 1 in the codes clause.

Comment: Right, done; I added the clause to the ON, thanks @Wrikken.

SELECT customers.*, count(codes.code) as codesused 
FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN codes ON customers.boxID = codes.boxID AND codes.retrieved = 1
GROUP BY customers.customerID